# Attachment in Emacs org mode

Tags: emacs

How could I attach Word document in my .org file?
I could do it for plain text file but not .doc type. 
Are the other options to point to Word file in my system other the attaché?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`C-c C-a` then you pick what fits you best: http://orgmode.org/manual/Attachments.html

Comment: Well ... I already tried that way. I attach file e.g. foo.docx but when I try to open that attachment it opens not the file but a list of .xml files. As I mentioned I don't have a problem with C-c C-a when the file is a plain text file. In my case it is a Word file. Again: could not text file be attached and the opened in org? In other words ... attachment is not a problem ... the problem is to open it

Comment: You cannot open a Word file in Org. But you may call Word or any other program to do the job, based on file extensions. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9116029/5494004